# Notifications react native chat app

Tags: firebase, react-native, notifications, firebase-notifications

I'm actually on a chat application using react-native and I have a database on firebase. I wanted to know how can I have notifications when a new message is posted on the app ? That's where I generate my messages :

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'
import firebaseService from '../../services/firebase'
import Component from './app/components/AuthScreen/AuthTabs/BasicForm/Component.js'

const FIREBASE_REF_MESSAGES = firebaseService.database().ref('/GeneralMessage')
const FIREBASE_REF_MESSAGES_LIMIT = 20

export const sendMessage = message => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(chatMessageLoading())

    let currentUser = firebaseService.auth().currentUser
    let createdAt = new Date().getTime()
    let chatMessage = {
      text: message,
      createdAt: createdAt,
      user: {
        id: currentUser.uid,
        email: currentUser.email,
      }
    }

    FIREBASE_REF_MESSAGES.push().set(chatMessage, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        dispatch(chatMessageError(error.message))
      } else {
        dispatch(chatMessageSuccess())
      }
    })
  }
}

export const updateMessage = text => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(chatUpdateMessage(text))
  }
}

export const loadMessages = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    FIREBASE_REF_MESSAGES.limitToLast(FIREBASE_REF_MESSAGES_LIMIT).on('value', (snapshot) => {
      dispatch(loadMessagesSuccess(snapshot.val()))
    }, (errorObject) => {
      dispatch(loadMessagesError(errorObject.message))
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Firebase Cloud Function** to send notification whenever there is new message or anything is changed in database.

Here i am sharing sample code.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notificationRequests/{values}').onCreate((event) => {

// Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
var itemVal = event.data.val()

// Notification details.
  const payload = {
    notification: {
    title: itemVal.title,
    body: itemVal.body,
    sound: 'default',

  },
  data: {
    otherData:"extra"
  },
};

// Set the message as high priority and have it expire after 24 hours.
const options = {
  contentAvailable: true,
  priority: 'high',
  timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24,
};

if (itemVal.tokens) {
  // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
  // registration token with the provided options.
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(itemVal.tokens, payload, options)
    .then((response) => {


    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error : ', error);

    });
} else {

}
});
```

Reference Links :

[Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)
[react-native-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-functions](https://medium.com/the-modern-development-stack/react-native-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-functions-74b832d45386)
https://aaronczichon.de/2017/03/13/firebase-cloud-functions/
[react-native-chat-app-serverless-firebase-push-notifications](https://school.shoutem.com/lectures/react-native-chat-app-serverless-firebase-push-notifications/)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft App Center Push enables you to send push notifications to users of your app from the App Center portal. App Center portal and the Push SDK is integrated with Firebase Cloud Messaging.